# How to import specific part from multi parts in MEF?

Tags: mef

I am using MEF as DI container and the problem is that I want to import specific part from multiple parts.

For example, I have following codes :

```
public interface IService
{
    void Send();
}

[Export(typeof(IService))]
public class Service : IService
{
    public void Send()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service.Send");
    }
}

[Export(typeof(IService))]
public class FakeService : IService
{
    public void Send()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FakeService.Send");
    }
}

[Import]
public IService Service { get; set; } // ---> let's say I want to use FakeService
```

Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can export metadata with your class, here's an example:

```
public interface ILogger
{
  void Log(string message);
}

[Export(typeof(ILogger)), ExportMetadata("Name", "Console")]
public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
{
  public void Log(string message)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(message);
  }
}

[Export(typeof(ILogger)), ExportMetadata("Name", "Debug")]
public class DebugLogger : ILogger
{
  public void Log(string message)
  {
    Debug.Print(message);
  }
}
```

Given that contract and those example implementations, we can import out types as `Lazy<T, TMetadata>` whereby we can define a metadata contract:

```
public interface INamedMetadata
{
  string Name { get; }
}
```

You don't need to worry about creating an implementation of the metadata, as MEF will project any `ExportMetadata` attribute values as concrete implementation of `TMetadata`, which in our example is `INamedMetadata`.  With the above, I can create the following example:

```
public class Logger
{
  [ImportMany]
  public IEnumerable<Lazy<ILogger, INamedMetadata>> Loggers { get; set; }

  public void Log(string name, string message)
  {
    var logger = GetLogger(name);
    if (logger == null)
      throw new ArgumentException("No logger exists with name = " + name);

    logger.Log(message);
  }

  private ILogger GetLogger(string name)
  {
    return Loggers
      .Where(l => l.Metadata.Name.Equals(name))
      .Select(l => l.Value)
      .FirstOrDefault();
  }
}
```

In that sample class, I am importing many instances, as `Lazy<ILogger, INamedMetadata>` instances.  Using `Lazy<T,TMetadata>` allows us to access the metadata before accessing the value.  In the example above, I'm using the `name` argument to select the appropriate logger to use.

If it is not right to instantiate the class on import, you can use an `ExportFactory<T,TMetadata>` which allows you to spin up instances of your types on demand. (`ExportFactory` is included in the Silverlight version of .NET 4.0, but Glenn Block did throw the source code [on codeplex](http://mef.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=207539) for Desktop/Web use.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the overload of Export that takes a contract name as well. Then import it with the contract name.

```
[Export("Service", typeof(IService))]
public class Service : IService {
}

[Export("FakeService", typeof(IService))]
public class FakeService : IService {
}

[Import("FakeService")]
public IService Service { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, I was trying to use contract name and it solved my problem, but I cannot use ImportMany if I use contract name in the Exports Parts. Is there any way to use ImportMany with Import specific part together?

Comment: Not really. In general you can't easily combine Import with ImportMany anyhow. Cause if you have an Import and there's more than one export, you'll hit the same exception. You could however ImportMany possibly in a constructor, then select one of the ones imported based on some other logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can add export metadata to distinguish the different exports from each other.  Then on the import side you will need to use an ImportMany and then filter it based on the metadata to find the one you want.