# How do I tell MEF which type I need for this interface?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, mef

I have following:

```
public interface IEmailService
    {
        bool SendEmail(MailMessage message);
    }

[Export(typeof(IEmailService))]
    public class SmtpEmailService : IEmailService
    {
}


[Export(typeof(IEmailService))]
    public class AmazonEmailService : IEmailService
    {
}
```

How do I import specific one based on some criteria?

For example, when I use service I have something like this:

```
public class MobileService
    {
        [Import] 
        public IEmailService EmailService { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to configure MEF in config file or any other place so it KNOWS automatically which version of `EmailService` to import?

Comment: I think that you can get all of them in a collection, and then select the one that you need based on your config file. Should be simple enough to code.

Comment: What would be the point? The purpose of MEF is to support add-in scenarios, so the consumer shouldn't dictate a particular dependency...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the name of the contract in your `Export` attribute while exporting and then use one of the names you exported in your `Import` attribute as below:

```
[Export("SmtpEmailService", typeof(IEmailService))]
public class SmtpEmailService : IEmailService {
}

[Export("AmazonEmailService", typeof(IEmailService))]
public class AmazonEmailService : IEmailService {
}

[Import("AmazonEmailService")]
public IEmailService EmailService { get; set; } //Import a specific type
```

In case you also want to use ImportMany, see the section [Exports and Metadata](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata&referringTitle=Guide) on http://mef.codeplex.com

There is also a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611706/how-to-import-specific-part-from-multi-parts-in-mef) which should help you.

Comment: Thank you! I guess thats an answer. I was hoping for some code-less config scenario where I would say in my `web.config` what MEF should import. This way I would switch it based on where I host solution.

Comment: @katit yes I believe some .config solution does exist but at the moment I dont have any knowledge and references about it, yo would need to google it a bit more..Thanks for accepting..